# Is there a path for other SE sites to have rep hidden by default like MathOverflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation, design, mathoverflow

Looking at MathOverflow, I noticed rep and badges from all users was hidden by default. It's a very interesting concept and I was just curious if another SE wanted to have their rep hidden by default, what would the process for that look like?

Comment: Like any change on any site. Gather consensus on your meta site and have a moderator tag it [status-review] so a community manager can get in touch with your sites mod team and discuss.

Comment: @Luuklag I was just curious if there was a specific flow like tag removal/denylisting.

Answer (score 9):

A majority of site-specific changes like that can be accomplished by first creating a discussion question on that site's meta site so that the community can participate in the change's proposal. If there's a need to increase the number of users who see the question so that folks can vote on it, a moderator can tag it with the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag to increase visibility, as that will feature it on that site's "Featured" panel.

Once community consensus is reached about such a change, if the change requires staff intervention, the discussion question can be tagged with [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) by a moderator, pushing that question to the staff team's internal tracking system where it can be triaged and handled by a member suitable for the task.

In this instance, MathOverflow moderators [have a different agreement with SE that allows them the ability to change some JavaScript on their site](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4430/161977) provided they contact SE staff and ask them to implement the changes. They asked for, and [implemented a change to hide reputation/badges](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5211/161977) following some consensus from the mod team. It was [well-received by the community](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5218/161977), especially considering it's opt-in (i.e. you can choose whether rep and badges are invisible for you or not in an easily-discoverable place).

If a site other than MathOverflow wanted to make a change like this, it would require a sizable amount of staff intervention, as other sites cannot ask for JavaScript adjustments. MathOverflow is unique in that way, as it is the only site that can currently request that JavaScript be adjusted/added.

Comment: Small note: their changes *also* require staff intervention. They don't have a tool to just edit the JavaScript for the site. The changes have to go through us and we add them to their site. They are just the only ones allowed to request JavaScript be added.

Comment: Dang, it would be quite nice if we could *request* to have JavaScript added to the site. While I wouldn't want this particular change, there's lots of other things which could be fixed/adjusted. We wouldn't be stuck with so many things that are "6–8". It would be even better if SE would make the site's JavaScript open source (given that JavaScript and CSS are inherently delivered as source, although minimized). [Note: While HTML is also delivered as source, it's really constructed using another language or languages. The source for that is *not* inherently open source.]

Comment: I've gone ahead and added that info in @animuson , thanks for clarifying. The phrasing on the MathOverflow meta post suggested to me that they were able to adjust it themselves, which given their agreement with SE didn't seem entirely outside of the realm of possibility, though it makes far more sense that it needs to go through you guys.

Comment: @Makyen while ideal, keep in mind someone needs to: 1) review the code, 2) test the code, 3) be available in case code change crash something. This is fine on one not-so-big site, but if having it on 170+ sites, not to mention SO.... they'll need to hire tons of people to handle it. Thinking out loud, maybe allow to request only once change per week...

Comment: Technically MO is a big site - just that they have 'unique' governance and someone responsible for things like this.