Why doesn't reputation show under usernames on MathOverflow?
I landed on a MathOverflow page from the Hot Network Questions (HNQ) section and I noticed that user reputation doesn't show under their username. why is that?



MathOverflow has some special agreement which allows them to customise things on their site.

See Reputation and badges are no longer visible next to the users' names

They also don't have the hot network questions in the sidebar.

Tangentially related: Mathoverflow - why so different. BTW if you want to see the reputation, you can change the settings (but the default is that it is not displayed): Viewing reputation and badges is now opt-in and compatible with the new front page.

Also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382074/152859
